# Trying to register a dll using regasm.exe silently

Tags: inno-setup

Trying to register a dll using Regasm.exe silently.The code is working but a splash of command prompt always appearing.

Windows 10

Filename:"{code:LocOfRegasm}"; Parameters: """StellarCreateMailbox.dll"" /codebase /SILENT"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; StatusMsg: "Registering controls ...";

No splash of command prompt must appear

Comment: runhidden flag is not working.It is still showing splash of regasm.exe